# AdvancedDataGrid - access dataProvider

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have AdvancedDataGrid and I wanted to access dataProvider.getItemAt(i) in function in my view.
I'm not getting any errors nor warning and the code is compiling, but when I run this function I get this error:
`Property getItemAt not found on mx.collections.HierarchicalCollectionView and there is no default value.`
Why can't I do this? I saw some samples ane people was using this function.
This is how I call it:

```
var x:Object = _dg.dataProvider.getItemAt(i);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AdvancedDataGrid](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/AdvancedDataGrid.html)'s [dataProvider](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/AdvancedListBase.html#dataProvider) is a generic object.  That, basically, means the compiler will let any property/method access on it slide without issues.

The [HierarchicalCollectionView](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/HierarchicalCollectionView.html) does not have a getItemAt() method, which is why you get the runtime error.  The Hierarchical collection, by nature, contains nested elements I'm not sure how you'd access a single element using a single index.

You probably want to use some form of [getChildren()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/HierarchicalCollectionView.html#getChildren%28%29) or [getParentItem()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/HierarchicalCollectionView.html#getParentItem%28%29) method to get access to an individual node.

The places where you saw [getItemAt()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#getItemAt%28%29) work were most likely using an [ArrayCollection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html).

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Can you help me with one more thing? When I use getParentItem() is there any possibility to get its index, which it has in my grid?

Comment: @PawełReszka "The Hierarchical collection, by nature, contains nested elements I'm not sure how you'd access a single element using a single index."   So, what index are you trying to access?  And in relation to what?  Are you talking about the row number in the grid?